# How could i set a random location for a button in java swing

Tags: java, swing

how would i randomly position a button on a certain portion of the frame. I have tried to set two variables x and y which are random but it doesn't work, the button disappears i'm guessing it is positioned off the screen.

Thi sis what i have tried:

```
int y = ran.nextInt(0 - frame.getHeight());
int x = ran.nextInt(0 - frame.getHeight());
```

I am also getting an error 'AWT-EventQueue -0'

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have a negetive value in the bracket.

```
int y = ran.nextInt(frame.getHeight());
int x = ran.nextInt(frame.getWidth());
```

Comment: 'AWT-EventQueue -0' When i add in a number before the frame.getHeight() and frame.getWidth() the error is not longer there but the button doesn't appear on the screen.

Comment: Sorry what is the stack trace

Answer (score 2):

1. not `frame.getHeight()` but `frame.getContentPane.getHeight(`)
2. required to use `AbsoluteLayout` for container where is `JButton` placed
3. add `(re)validate` and `repaint` to container where is `JButton` placed
4. use `JPanel` as container for `JButton`